# CSS width and height not working for div with display: inline

Tags: css

I want to set certain width and height for div elements. My css contain this

```
.icon {display: inline; height: 80px!important; width: 80px!important;border: 1px solid #000}
.icon-usd {
    background: url(../images/usd-icon.png) no-repeat;
}
```

but when I run my page it doesn't apply the styles. Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uyv2qopr/)

Comment: `display: inline-block;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`display:inline` elements are rendered inline - meaning they do not respect width and height declarations but just 'go with the flow'.

You probably intend to use `display:inline-block` instead, making it behave like a block element itself, but follow the parent's flow as an inline element.

[The fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/uyv2qopr/2/).

Answer (score 0):

use `display:inline-block`

you can't give height and width for `inline` elements

[check the **DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vgxLtxus/)